# How to calculate Ride length between two date/time columns in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have two columns in tableau "Started_time" and "ended_time", they are both in "date/time" format, when i try to calculate the "total duration" from these two columns it always pulls up data as a string.

My goal is to caculate the AVG time in "total duration" and when i try to do a caculation with this newly calculated column "total duration"  an error pops up "AVG cant do a calculation on a string".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8XiZ.png)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGbGM.png)]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daGtT.png)

I dont know if I should go back to SQL and change the data type to float???

Answer (score 0):

Your second two images are the same (Started Time).  Double check that both are in the Date/Time format.  For total duration, create a Calculated Field and try using the DATEDIFF function:

```
DATEDIFF('month', [Started_time], [ended_time])
```

Change the interval (substitute *month* with *years*, *weeks*, *days*, etc.)

[More info on Date Functions here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_date.htm).